# Use factory pattern when using different properties based on a property value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

In a Web API 2 project I have a model OrderLine (nested object of a Order model). A client can Post data and via `IValidatableObject` I validate my model. Simplyfied, my models looks like this:

```
public class Order {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderLine> orderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Type == 'A'")]
    public string DeliveryType { get; set; }

    public IENumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext      validationContext)
    {
        if(Type.ToUpper() == "A")
        {
            var item = ItemCode + DeliveryType;

            using(MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext))
            {
                var items = db.Items.Where(q => q.ItemCode == item.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();
                if(items == null)
                {
                    yield return new ValidationResult("The conbination of ItemCode and ConfactionType is not allowed");
                }
            }
        }

        if(Type.ToUpper() == "B")
        {
            using(MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext))
            {
                var items = db.Items.Where(q => q.ItemCode == item.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();
                if(items == null)
                {
                    yield return new ValidationResult("The field ItemCode does not contain a valid code");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the value of the OrderLine.Type property I know what kind of OrderLine type I'm going to write to the database. In the above class, I only have a few properties, but Imagine that, depending on the type, I have multiple different properties and validation rules. Based on [this post](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/designpatterns/FUcV280513-Factory-Method-Design-Pattern---C) I was wondering if I should use something like a factory so something like this:

```
public class OrderLineA : OrderLine
{
    // some properties
    // some validation rules
}

public class OrderLineB : OrderLine
{
    // some (other) properties
    // some (other) validation rules
}
```

Comment: so you want to validate orderlineA and orderlineB, thats it right? i can propose a solution which won't follow a factory pattern

Comment: i tried this way, didn't work out. ICollection<OrderLine> was filled with only the properties of OrderLine, even though i sent properties of OrderLineA in it. Properties of OrderLineA was just ignored. I think this is what we mean by a DTO, have all the properties(properties of OrderLineA + OrderLineB) in a DTO called OrderLineDTO. then based on the OrderLine.Type create your OrderLineX objects. About validation of OrderLineX properties, call a validate method on OrderLineDTO and use switch case to validate only your OrderLineA or OrderLineB properties.

Comment: @singsuyash So basically, I have an OrderLine object, this is exposed to the client via my web api 2 controller: public IActionResult Post(Order order) where OrderLine is the nested object. Then create a new OrderLineDto instance and do the validation like I first described on OrderLine. When the values passes the validation, offer the dto to my repository, map OrderLineDto with Data_Line and save the data? (using EF where the object is called Data_Line <-- is provided to me, so can't change that)

Comment: Order contains OrderLine, thats ok, when the client posts a json that contains Order properties, and OrderLine properties, they will be mapped to the object in our controller action. we are fine till here. My question is , how do you get input for the properties of OrderLineA , OrderLineB? My previous comment focuses on this problem.

Comment: @singsuyash Maybe I was not totally clear in my question, but that is exactly my issue. because I have different types of order lines, I thought maybe I should approach this problem with the factory pattern instead of having a model with all the properties. that's why I came up with the OrderLineA / B idea.

Comment: i tried sending in this json {
  id:5,
  name:"orderdtoname",
  orderDetails:
  [
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "orderlineA",
      fooA: 7,
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "orderlineB",
      fooB: 9,
    }
  ]
} didn't work. only things it picked up were the properties of OrderLine. i think u need one single class with all the properties. AFAIK, mvc model binding works with name comparison. i think you might need to write your own model binder.